# Calling a view depending on the layout

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm busy creating a cms and in the backend I have a section where you can choose the layout of a page. At the moment the layout's name gets saved into the database and I would like to be able to do something like this:
If contact is the same as the layouts.contact then show the contact.blade.php.
"contact" is the layout's name that was saved in the database from the backend and if "home" is selected then home.blade.php needs to be shown.

I tried to create a helper but its not showing anything

```
function getTypeLayout($type = '')
{

$layout = Page::where('type', '=', $type)->get();

switch($layout){
    case "home":
        echo "home layout";
        break;
    case "inside":   
        echo "inside layout"; 
}

return $type;
}
```

and in my home.blade.php

```
{{ getTypeLayout() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a master template. In this master page  you can insert content

```
<html>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This content page looks like

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('sidebar')


    <p>This is appended to the master sidebar.</p>
@stop

@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@stop
```

In your controller you can decide which content you are going to use by the DB value

```
protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

public function showLayout()
{
    $this->layout->content = View::make('<DBvalue>.layout');
}
```